# Can't verify Wordpress in Google Search Console

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I have been figuratively banging my head against a wall and literally ripping my hair out in frustration over this. This is the issue:

1. I need to make my webpage tied to my  name, i.e. when you search my name the page pops up. Thus I need to verify my webpage on google search console
2. All the methods for doing this somehow require me entering code into the HTML of my front page
3. This cannot be edited from Wordpress online, thus I must install Wordpress
4. Wordpress installation requires that I first install FTP, which requires FTP username and password, which Wordpress does not want to give me.

Thus, I am totally unable to achieve my first goal (connect my webpage to my name). Is there a way to achieve this without having to download Wordpress, which is turning into a huge pain in the ass? I use a free version of Wordpress.

Comment: [Look into this article for validating Wordpress.com sites with Google](https://en.support.wordpress.com/webmaster-tools/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can insert the Google Console verification meta on a Wordpress.com hosted site.

Go to settings > SEO
Direct URL: https://wordpress.com/settings/seo/

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your webpage in Google Search Console using Google Analytics. It is one of the alternate methods for the verification. Google Analytics support on WordPress.com is available as a feature of the WordPress.com Business plan. Visit Settings → Analytics under My Sites to enable Google Analytics.

Another option would be to verify via DNS and your domain name provider. Detailed instructions how to set up a CNAME record for that are available within the Google Search Console. With this option, you do not need to edit the front page HTML too.